# How can I read Instruments?

Tags: xcode, profiling, xcode6, instruments

I have Xcode 6 and the labels in Instruments seem to have changed from the last time I looked at it. Used to be that Live Bytes represented the total amount of memory the application was consuming and now I have other columns. Right clicking on the columns shows a number of other values to be added but not no more Live Bytes.

How do I know how much memory my application is currently consuming and not the total? Is it `Persistent Bytes`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the Persistent Bytes column shows how much memory your application is currently using. The Live Bytes column changed to Persistent Bytes in Xcode 6.